# Connection in Java to a Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I'm working on OS X, Eclipse, Java 8 and MySQLWorkBench.

I realize with the last a database (can I say schema?), named "mydb" located at localhost:3306 (I don't know exactly what it means)...

Now I would like to connect via a java program to this db.
I'm trying with

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
```

It follows the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException:
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You need to include the MySQL JDBC driver in the classpath while you're running your Java application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download the jdbc driver and add it to your project

[Download the driver from here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

[Example on how to add the driver in eclipse](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44)

Also you need to include the username and password in the connection statement and make sure you call the Class for name to get the driver loaded

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

Comment: Done it, but it continue to not work... exactly same error message. I think i left default username "root" and no password, could it be possible?

Comment: If the driver is loaded as a library then it should work. Try removing all your imports at the top of the class and re-importing them with ctrl+shift+o

Comment: Edited the answer to add the Class.forName call this might be what you are missing

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zPeWb.png

Comment: You have added the zip extract it and add the driver jar only

Comment: Unfortunately no... even just the line

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

seems not to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108969/discussion-between-jacques-ramsden-and-marco).

Comment: Have you extracted and added the jar only?  Please post a screen shot of the libs after you have done that

Comment: The code in this example works perfectly. I would suggest trying to create a new project copy paste the code in. The only thing you need to do to get it working would be to add the correct jdbc-mysql.jar file into the lib of the project. See example here.   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added required library to connect java application with MySql database.you can download it form [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector.jar.zip).After once you get downloaded , just extract zip wherever you want.And add it into your project library folder.
Right click on project goto property -> java build path -> add external jar .

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","userName","userPass");
```

where `userName` is your database username and `userPass` is your password corresponding to that user.

Answer (score 0):

After download and adding the Connector/J to your build path like @Jacques said.

Try this code:

```
try {
        // Load the JDBC driver
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class driver_class = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Driver driver = (Driver) driver_class.newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", getDbUser(), getDbPassword());
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Where getDbUser() is your database username and getDbPassword() is your database password.